# Why my missing values are being replaced by something different than what I want? Python

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I am trying to replace missing data from my dataframe.
Some of the data is replaced correctly according to what I want but the rest doesn't work.

For instance, I want to fill the missing data for my ['Gender'] column.
I tried 2 different methods:

- Replacing using the Mode

```
for column in ['Gender']:
    df[column].fillna(df[column].mode().index[0], inplace = True)
```

It works for more than 95% of the missing data, but for some missing data it replaced it with '0' rather than the mode (Male or Female).

- So I tried a second method, replacing by Random

```
df['Gender'].fillna(lambda x: random.choice(df[df[Gender] != np.nan]['Gender']), inplace =True)
```

Same problem about 95% is replaced correctly and the rest gives me the following as replaced data:

> <function  at 0x000001F4BB66DF70>

instead of Male or Female.

Does anybody know why and how to fix this issue?

Comment: `fillna` can not take a function as a argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get ZERO because you are passing the index, you should instead write:

```
for column in ['Gender']:
    df[column].fillna(df[column].mode()[0], inplace = True)
```

Comment: Thanks, that did solve the issue for the mode. Do you know how I should do it if I want random data?

Comment: Why do you want to go via random? It is much more complicated

Comment: Because I am afraid the mode might skew the data in one direction(especially if I have a lot of data missing), while random might give me a more homogenous solution for the missing data. In any case, I can deleted the rows with missing data but that's not ideal since it will also remove useful data.